# builder.Services.AddGraphClient can not be found - Blazor Webassembly

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0, microsoft-entra-id

I am trying to follow the microsoft documentation on configuring blazor to read roles from entra Id.

I have the following in the client program.cs file

However it is telling me that the AddGraphClient method is not found as I am missing an assembly.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState,
    CustomUserAccount>(options =>
    {
        builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd",options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(builder.Configuration["Client:AzureAd:AccessTokenUrl"]);
    })
    .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount,
        CustomAccountFactory>();

var baseUrl = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")["BaseUrl"];
var scopes = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes")
    .Get<List<string>>();

builder.Services.AddGraphClient(baseUrl, scopes);
```

I have the following Using statements at the top of the program.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Graph;
```

What do I need to do to get it to recognise AddGraphClient? The project is .net8

Answer (score 0):

That is because the extension method isn't defined anywhere, you need to write it yourself. The code is in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/graph-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=graph-sdk-5#hosted-blazor-webassembly-solutions):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Authentication;
using IAccessTokenProvider = 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider;

internal static class GraphClientExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddGraphClient(
            this IServiceCollection services, string? baseUrl, List<string>? scopes)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl) || scopes.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            return services;
        }

        services.Configure<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>>(
            options =>
            {
                scopes?.ForEach((scope) =>
                {
                    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(scope);
                });
            });

        services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationProvider, GraphAuthenticationProvider>();

        services.AddScoped(sp =>
        {
            return new GraphServiceClient(
                new HttpClient(),
                sp.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationProvider>(),
                baseUrl);
        });

        return services;
    }

    private class GraphAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration config;

        public GraphAuthenticationProvider(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider,
            IConfiguration config)
        {
            TokenProvider = tokenProvider;
            this.config = config;
        }

        public IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider { get; }

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(RequestInformation request, 
            Dictionary<string, object>? additionalAuthenticationContext = null, 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var result = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken(
                new AccessTokenRequestOptions()
                {
                    Scopes = 
                        config.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph:Scopes").Get<string[]>()
                });

            if (result.TryGetToken(out var token))
            {
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", 
                    $"{CoreConstants.Headers.Bearer} {token.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```